# Is there any method to compile libuv with android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, libuv

we are now developing some features with c/c++ for android client.

So we will use android NDK - r8 to compile our code.

We use libuv also in our code.

Unfortunately, android NDK cannot complie libuv correctly. All the terms started with 'pthread_'cannot be recognized.

Anyone has idea or hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can's compile or can't link? Pthreads are supported on NDK.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: unfortunately, NDK does not provide `pthread_barrier_t` and some others.

Answer (score 2):

The support for android is not yet in mainline libuv, but I know of at least two patch-sets to fix it:

- [As implemented in rust](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6567)
- [As a recently submitted pull-request](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/pull/805)

While I can't speak of the latter (seemingly very good quality), I can tell you that the former is currently being used for the Android port of rust and servo.

Comment: If using on Android-15 or previous, use this patch too: http://www.nadavos.com/patch-nodejs-to-run-on-android-4-04/